# Is there a head equivalent to tail -f in Linux?

Tags: linux

I have a constantly changing file and I wish to view the first n lines.Is this possible?

Comment: Your file is being written to at the beginning ? Surely the first n lines will always be the same ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Use `watch` with it instead.

Comment: Specifically the usage would be: `watch -n 2 head filename` to check watch the head looks like every two seconds. Use `watch -d` to highlight differences.